# select shows the top record in the db and not the selected

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I have a select on a form that updates the backend db ok.  My problem is that when the form is displayed, it always shows the top record in the db and not the selected.

I've googled and read answers on stackoverflow among others but everything I try either doesn't work or breaks functionality.

$registrants points to a select on a registrants table.
$affiliates points to a select on an affiliates table

Here is the select:

```
<select name="affiliate_id" class="form-control"> 
   <?php foreach($affiliates as $display => $value) { ?>
       <option value='<?= $value['affiliate_id'] ?>' <?php if($registrants['affiliate_id'] == $value['affiliate_id']) { ?>selected='selected'<?php } ?>><?= $value['affiliate_name'] ?>
       </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Thanks for looking it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clean up your code a bit and create a variable $selected, which either is empty or a string 'selected':

```
<select name="affiliate_id" class="form-control"> 
    <?php 
        foreach($affiliates as $value):
            $selected=$registrants['affiliate_id'] == $value['affiliate_id']?'selected':'';
    ?>
            <option value="<?=$value['affiliate_id']?>" <?=$selected?> >
                <?= $value['affiliate_name'] ?>
            </option>
    <?php 
        endforeach;
    ?>
</select>
```

or you could use the CI function [form_dropdown()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=option#form_dropdown), for that don't forget to load the form helper. This method simplifies a bit the use of drop down lists:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$data=array('class'=>'$affiliates');
// get the selected item
<?php 
    foreach($affiliates as $value){
        $selected=$registrants['affiliate_id'] == $value['affiliate_id']?$value['affiliate_id']:'';
        if($selected){break;}
    }
?>
<?=form_dropdown('affiliate_id', $affiliates, $selected, $data);?>
```

Comment: I tried the code (not helper) and got the same results.  Db updated, but select doesn't show correct value when form displays.

Comment: then you have no match for `$registrants['affiliate_id'] == $value['affiliate_id']`, check those values

Comment: I check  the values coming into the form. print_r shows the correct value for $registrants.affiliate_id.  This is the one I'm trying to match.  $value is the record from the affiliates table that is being parsed.  so if registrants_id = affiliate_id then it is selected.  The code looks like it should work.

Comment: You didn't show your data structure, are those arrays or arrays of objects? Is $affiliates a flat array or nested (if nested you need a 2nd foreach loop). Maybe you could add the print_r output for the 1st entry of $affiliates and of $registrants to your question?

Comment: Found the issue, it was obscured by query parameters, the affiliate table was joined but did not return any rows due to a mismatch of user_id and registrant_id.  Have to push the registrant_id into the equation. Thanks for the heads up on checking the data.  New to CI, php and bootstrap and appreciate the help :)